# Typeform Error: JSONP request to https://admin.typeform.com/app/embed/ID?jsoncallback=? failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, request, next.js, typeform

I'm having this error
`Error: JSONP request to https://admin.typeform.com/app/embed/id?jsoncallback=? Failed` trying to embed a typeform in my next js app.

I'm using the library react-typeform-embed.

My code:`<ReactTypeformEmbed url="https://form.typeform.com/to/id?typeform-medium=embed-snippet" />`

Comment: It returns a 404 error. Why do you expect it to work?

Comment: In the snippet you shared, looks like you didn't replace the `id` by the id of your form.
Or did you?

Comment: @NicolasGrenié I did... I only replaced it here.

Comment: @Quentin thats because I replaced the real id for 'ID' in the url..

Comment: @Emiliano What version of `react-typeform-embed` are you using? Can you try updating to the latest one?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to resolve this issue and I believe it is because the `react-typeform-embed` library uses an older version of `@typeform/embed`. Don't know when/if they'll fix it but here is a work around example using the generic `@typeform/embed` and some hooks.

```
import { createWidget } from '@typeform/embed'
import '@typeform/embed/build/css/widget.css'
import { useEffect } from 'react';


const Container = () => {
    let form = '';
    useEffect(() => {
        form = createWidget('your form id', { container: document.querySelector('#form') })
    })
    return (
        <div id='form'>
            {form && form}
        </div>
    )
}



export default Container;
```

For reference, I'd suggest checking out the vanilla `@typeform/embed` docs: https://developer.typeform.com/embed/vanilla/

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a react package with @typeform/embed called "embed-react". https://github.com/Typeform/embed/tree/main/packages/embed-react

Use this package and your problem should be fixed.